# How to search result set from a result set

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a problem to search result from a result set.

I search order based on customer id and store in rs, then I want to search payment based on order id from rs and store in rs2.

This rs2 will then bind in datagridview.

But I found that rs2 will keep reassign the previous data once new data found, so the final result always show the one result which is the last result found. I try use Static rs2 but it still not work.

Hope some expert can provide solution. Thank you.

```
Private Sub BindCard()
  Dim name As String = cboCreditType.Text
  Dim db As New ConcertDataContext()

  Dim rs = From o In db.orders Where (o.customer_id = MemberLogin.id)

  Dim allOrders = From id In rs Select id.order_id

  Dim rs2 = From o In db.payments
            Where (name = "All" Or o.creditType = name) And
                  allOrders.Contains(o.order_id)
            Select o.payment_id, o.total_payment, o.creditNumber, o.creditType, o.order_id

  dgv.DataSource = rs2 'Error occurs here'
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using a loop here. Instead you should execute just one query to retrieve all records whose orderid is in the first query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly identified the problem in your code, the solution is pretty simple.

Remove the loop, extract a list of orderid to process and then use that list as a condition with Contains against the payments data

```
' First extract a list of all orders ID present in the orders selected
Dim allOrders = from id in rs select id.orderid

' Then use that list and select only the payments for those orders
rs2 = From o In db.payments 
        Where (name = "All" Or o.creditType = name) And 
        (allOrders.Contains(o.order_id))
              Select o.payment_id, o.total_payment, o.creditNumber, o.creditType, o.order_id
```

If you don't need all the data in rs then you can replace the initial query with

```
Dim allOrders = From o In db.orders 
                  Where (o.customer_id = MemberLogin.id)
                  Select o.order_Id
```

Comment: I had used your suggested way but it prompted out an arror: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Sorry, I was gone away, On what line did you get the exception?

Comment: I had edited the code above. The error occur at the last list before `End Sub`. At first, I assumed that maybe there were no data from database which cause this error, as I also did not do any validation yet. But I pretty sure I had key in some data before I run the code.

Comment: Setting the DataSource could trigger a cascade of events. Check if you have any DataGridView event and if the error happens there. Of course I assume that the _dgv_ itself is not null. Use the debugger put breakpoints in those events and see if anyone is triggered by the setting.